# Is it possible to style a <button> like a <a>?

Tags: html, css

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NcCVj/) code :

```
button
{
}

a:link, a:visited
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:red;
}

a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

<button>Link Button</button>

<a href='#'>Link A</a>
```

is it possible on CSS have the same design of the `<a>` to the `<button>`?
CSS 2 I hope, cross-browser on IE7+ and so on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just want the button to look like the link right?

http://jsfiddle.net/NcCVj/1/

The fonts are different but I think you get the gist of it.  The key is setting background and border to none (or to whatever matches your link)

Comment: I've updated it http://jsfiddle.net/NcCVj/3/ ..but on Firefox there is a space between text1 and text2 : on chrome not...why? Also, on IE there are some margin/padding that I can't avoid...

Comment: that's kind of a different question...  but I can indulge you i suppose.  Generally you should use a [css reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) to help minimize the differences between browser rendering.  Lots of people these days are also talking about [browser normalization](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/) rather than reset.  Again it's just to help deal with the differences in browser rendering.  I wasn't able to remove some of the spacing between elements, but it will at least make things a bit more consistent.

Comment: use the reset, it will help you a lot.  As for dealing with minute spacing, I'd suggest having all of your elements in tags, not just as text elements.  This will likely help you out a lot.  I did answer the original question right?